# variable declaration in javascript(global vs local)

Tags: javascript

I'm not able to understand the following code

```
function test() {
  let a = b = 0;
  a++;
  return a;
}

test();
typeof a;
typeof b;
```

getting type of a as undefined whereas typeof b as "number"

Comment: `let a` makes `a` scoped to the function. But `b` is not declared with `let` - it's just a `b = 0` which means it's an implicit global.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is scoping rules. variables that are declared by the keyword var are scoped to the immediate function body while let variables are scoped to the immediate enclosing block denoted by { }, meaning blocker scoped.
This is the reason why let keyword was introduced to the language. the function scope can be very confusing and can cause many bugs in JavaScript.

So, what you're seeing in the code is a decleration of let a that makes it scoped to the function. hence, the typeof a outside of the function is indeed undefined (since that area of code is not aware of a).
b, on the other hand, is not declared with let. it's being assigned to the number 0, meaning it's an implicit global variable, hence existing out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here when the foo() function executions starts java script interpreter

1. creates **variable a** in the scope of f00() function
2. for **variable b** the interpreter thinks it is accidentally created so the interpreter creates a global variable b and assigns value 0 eg: **(window.b = 0; or b = 0;)**
   this is because scoping rules here var keyword will be scoped to the immediate variable store (eg: a)
   so
3. type of **variable a is undefined** as it is in the scope of function foo()
4. type of **variable b is number** as it is **global variable** and is available anywhere in the code

Comment: "*the interpreter thinks it is accidentally created*" the interpreter doesn't think any such thing. It just follows the rules. Assigning to undeclared variable instead assigns to the property of the global object. Assuming you're not in strict mode. Doesn't matter whether it was accidental or not and the interpreter certainly won't try to judge which one it was.